# cv2.cv for Python 2.7 32 bit in an OpenCV sample code

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv

I am trying to understand how edge detection works and was trying the code from OpenCV below on Py 2.7, 32 bit:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

img = cv2.imread('SiliconPost.jpeg',0)

laplacian = cv2.Laplacian(img,cv2.CV)
sobelx = cv2.Sobel(img,cv2.CV,1,0,ksize=5)
sobely = cv2.Sobel(img,cv2.CV,0,1,ksize=5)

plt.subplot(2,2,1),plt.imshow(img,cmap = 'gray')
plt.title('Original'), plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
plt.subplot(2,2,2),plt.imshow(laplacian,cmap = 'gray')
plt.title('Laplacian'), plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
plt.subplot(2,2,3),plt.imshow(sobelx,cmap = 'gray')
plt.title('Sobel X'), plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
plt.subplot(2,2,4),plt.imshow(sobely,cmap = 'gray')
plt.title('Sobel Y'), plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])

plt.show()
```

But I keep coming across an error:
 `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'CV'`

How do I go about rectifying this error?

Comment: Did you `import cv2`? Is OpenCV properly installed? Try to run `help(cv2)` to see what happens. Note: post the code you are trying to run in the question, not the link.

Comment: Yes, I did `import cv2`, but I might have messed up the installation. Let me try `help(cv2)`.

Comment: @KelvinS, I shall post the code right away. Thank you!

Comment: @KelvinS I am getting the error `NameError: name 'cv2' is not defined`. Does this mean that OpenCV is not installed correctly?

Comment: @KelvinS, actually, I took out `.CV` on a hunch and it worked. It gives another error now: `TypeError: an integer is required`.

Comment: Why did you take off the `.CV` portions? With your current implementation, you're passing the entire opencv library into your `Laplacian` and `Sobel` methods which makes no sense. Put them back and update your question to reflect the new code and thrown error(s) if any.

Comment: What version of OpenCV are u running?

Comment: @eshirima, I am running 3.2.0 OpenCV.

Comment: @eshirima, oh okay. I can do that. I just took the `.CV` off on a hunch and it seemed to work.

Comment: @S_SDhar you got `NameError: name 'cv2' is not defined` probably because you didn't run `import cv2`. You need to run `import cv2` and then `help(cv2)`. Note: this is just to check if OpenCV is installed and working correctly

Comment: @S_SDhar Check my updated answer and let me know if it resolves your issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html?highlight=laplacian#laplacian), `ddepth` is the second parameter which defines the depth of the output image and is of type `int`.

What you passed to it; `cv2.CV`, is nothing. I believe its a typo and you meant to type either `cv2.CV_64F` or `cv2.CV_16S` or something along these lines.

Refer back to your tutorial to see what was used but you are looking for something along those lines.

**Side Note:**
`CV_16S`, `CV_64F` etc are default variables in OpenCV of type `int`. You can see this from their [implementation](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/05b15943d6a42c99e5f921b7dbaa8323f3c042c6/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/hal/interface.h).

Comment: It did for sure! Thank you!